# Problem with cookie vinaikoop jsmessage extesnion

Tags: magento-enterprise, javascript, prototype-js

We are using vinaikoop jsmessage extension to show the success, error message because we have FPC/varnish on our website.

There is issue with this extension, like it save messages inside a cookie which name is jsmessages, so after displaying the mesages it set the value '-' instead of actual value as per code. But it do not like we reload the page it again show the previous messages from the same cookie on page.

so I tried to debug the js code using developer tool but there were a surprise because when I add the breakpoint on the location where we are saving the jsmeesages value to '-', it worked fine. So whenever I used breakpoint into the js code it always works fine.

But when I removed the breakpoint and run the code it create the problem. I used console.log to know the value when we are saving the cookie then nothing find wrong with code.

I am not able to know the reason of issue. Below is the extension js code:-

```
var JsMessages = Class.create();
JsMessages.prototype = {
    initialize: function(data) {
        this.domain = data.domain;
        this.cookie = data.cookie;
        this.wrapper = '#vinaikopp-jsmessages';
        this.messages = decodeURIComponent(Mage.Cookies.get(this.cookie));
        if (this.messages && this.messages !== '-') {
            var cookie_name = this.cookie; // 'jsmessages'
            [this.domain, '.' + this.domain].each(function(domain) {
                console.log('domain:- ' + domain); // it show domain.com
                console.log('Cookie Path:- ' + Mage.Cookies.path); // path:- '/'
                console.log('Cookie Expiry:- ' + Mage.Cookies.expires);// expiry:- null
                var result = Mage.Cookies.set(cookie_name, '-', Mage.Cookies.expires, Mage.Cookies.path, domain);
                console.log('Cookie set result:- ' + result );
                console.log('Cookie messages:-' + this.messages); // message:- '-'
            });
            document.observe('dom:loaded', this.renderMessages.bind(this));
        }
    },
renderMessages: function()
{
    var type, messages = JSON.parse(this.messages);

    for(type in messages) {
        if (messages.hasOwnProperty(type) && messages[type].length) {
            this.renderMessage(type, messages[type]);
        }
    }
},
renderMessage: function(type, messages)
{
    var container, content = '';
    if (container = this.getMessagesElement(type)) {
        messages.each(function(message) {
            content += "<li>" + decodeURIComponent(message) + "</li>\n";
        });
        container.update("<ul>\n" + content + "</ul>")
        container.show();
    }
},
getMessagesElement: function(type)
{
    var elements = $$(this.wrapper + ' .' + type + '-msg');
    if (elements.length) {
        return elements[0];
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

After successful loading the page when I try to get value

```
decodeURIComponent(Mage.Cookies.get('jsmessages'));
```

it show the messages instead of '-'.

I put the console.log inside core magento cookie.js file to know might be there is some code which is saving the same value again but unfortunately didn't find anything.

Please let me know if anyone have the solution.

Here is the plugin github url:- https://github.com/Vinai/VinaiKopp_JsMessages

Comment: Your cookie might be cached by varnish...

Comment: No its not a varnish issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution,

**Reason of problem as per my understanding :-** 
As per my understanding this was happening because in each resource request we have same header , so extension was deleted the cookie before loading all the resources while resources which were not loaded yet had the same cookie in their header with previous value.

**Solution:-**
just deleted the same cookie after loading the page using jQuery(window).lod()